# how to generate a string from complex format similiar to regular expression?

Tags: expression, string.format

We know String.format() can accept format with such style:
`%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion`
which is well known as C printf() format, and introduced in java 1.5.

My task is, generating complex format including repeated or optional parameters.
For example, with the format:

```
select %1 from %2 where %3 and give %1->'*' %2->'users' %3->'age>20'
```

it returned:

```
select * from users where age>20
```

the format can be supported by Stirng.format().

However, I expect a format similar to:

```
select %1{, } from (%2(as %3)){,} (where %4 (and %5))?
when: %1->'*', %2->'users' %3->null, %3->'age>20'
```

it returned:

```
select * from users where age>20
when: %1->Stirng{'name','age'} , %2->'users' %3->'u', %4->'age>20', %5->null
```

it returned:

```
select name, age from users as u where age>20
when: %1->Stirng{'name','age'} , %2->'users' %3->'u', %4->null, %5->null
```

it returned:

```
select name, age from users as u
when: %1->Stirng{'name','age'} , %2->String{'users','order'} %3->{'u','o'}, %4->'age>20',    %5->'u.id=o.userid'
```

it returned:

```
select name, age from users as u,orders as o where age>20 and u.id=o.userid
```

I think now you may understand my meanings. Are there a mature library to do such complex 'anti-regexp' work?

Comment: i have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: %1 to %5 are parameters. Considering  %1->Stirng{'name','age'} , %2->String{'users','order'} %3->{'u','o'}, %4->'age>20',    %5->'u.id=o.userid'

Comment: I hope got 'select name, age from users as u,orders as o where age>20 and u.id=o.userid'

Comment: A regexp 'select\s+(\w)(,\s*(\w))*\s+from\s+(\w+)(\s+(\w+))?(,\s*(\w+)(\s+(\w+))?)*(\s+where\s+([=\w\.]+(\s+and\s+([=\w\.]+)?))? can fetch parameters from the string  'select name, age from users as u,orders as o where age>20 and u.id=o.userid'

Comment: However, I wanna getting the original string from the regexp and matching results. Now you understand?

Comment: regexp+string -> matched results

Comment: but matched results+regexp -> string?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for a CustomFormatProvider?

```
class SqlFormatter:IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
    {

        public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
        {
            return this;
        }


        public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
        {
            StringBuilder concat = new StringBuilder();

            string[] formatParts = format.Split(':');

            switch (formatParts[0])
            {
                case "sqlfield":
                    string sep = "";
                    if (formatParts.Length>1)
                    {
                        sep = formatParts[1];
                    }
                    string[] fields = (string[]) arg;
                    concat.Append(fields[0]);
                    for (int fieldIndex = 1; fieldIndex < fields.Length; fieldIndex++)
                    {
                        concat.Append(sep);
                        concat.Append(fields[fieldIndex]);
                    }
                    break;
                case "sqltables":
                    concat.Append(arg.ToString());
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return concat.ToString(); 
        }
    }
```

Use it like this:

```
 String sql = String.Format(
           new SqlFormatter()
           , "select {0:sqlfield:,} from {1:sqltables} "
           , new string[]{"name","lname"}
           , "person" );
```

Will give:
"select name,lname from person "

I'll leave the rest of the implementation (and robustness etc) to you...

Comment: +1 I think the posted wants it for Java (it's unspecified), but I generally like it -- could extract away from the format provider entirely depending upon situation and clean up according to tastes.

Comment: rene's answer uses C#? In java String.Format() we can not use custom format parser. I know the problem can be done by coding myself. I also expect a mature package can do this job completely.

Comment: C# seems more elaborate than java, as the latter.